# How do I change ng-class on window resize?

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-class

I have functionality where when I shrink the screen below a certain size and click on a table row it reveals other items in that table row. (white screen on left).

[image]

Then when I expand the window I want all table rows to return to normal, but I have a bug where if it's open already it won't close.
[image]

I tried setting the $scope.showIt variable to true/false, but it only seems to have an effect if it's the opposite of the initial $scope.showIt value.  How do I change all the ng-classes in every td when the screen is a certain size?

This is my html:

```
<tr class="table-body  "ng-repeat="service in services | orderBy:myOrderBy | filter:search">
    <td align="center" valign="middle" ng-click="showIt = dropDetails(showIt)" ng-class="{'name-show':showIt, 'name-show-disabled':!showIt}">{{ service.name }}</td>
    <td  ng-class="{'show':showIt, 'show-disabled':!showIt}">{{ service.description }}</td>
    <td  ng-class="{'show':showIt, 'show-disabled':!showIt}">{{ service.prices }}</td>
</tr>
```

And in my controller:

```
$scope.dropDetails = function(showIt){ //This function works well. 
    console.log(window)     
    console.log(window.innerWidth)      
    if(window.innerWidth < 760){
        return !showIt;
    }else{
        return showIt;
    }

}

var w = angular.element($window);
var resizeId=0; 
$scope.showIt = true;

w.bind('resize ', function (a) {
        clearTimeout(resizeId);
        resizeId = setTimeout(function(){

        if(w[0].innerWidth < 760){

        }else{

            $scope.showIt = true;  //Does nothing. 
            $scope.$apply();

        }                   
        }, 500);
})
```

Comment: You never set `$scope.showIt` to `false`. Is that typo ?

Comment: @AdnanUmer The `dropDetails` function sets it to false on ng-click

Comment: `if(window.innerWidth < 760){
        return !showIt;
    }`

Comment: How is the variable "w" getting re-set once the window gets large again?

Comment: `w[0].innerWidth` changes on window resize accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do use `Dot Rule` while defining `ng-model` in Angular view. So that will help you to follow prototypal inheritance while refering to there property.

The reason here is, you have used `ng-repeat`(which does create prototypically inherited child scope while rendering template each time on view). Here the same thing you need to do. Define model like `$scope.model` and inside that define `showIt` property. Rather you should put that `showIt` on each of you element of `services`, by which you handle each event individually.

**Markup**

```
<tr class="table-body" ng-repeat="service in services | orderBy:myOrderBy | filter:search">
    <td align="center" valign="middle" 
      ng-click="service.showIt= dropDetails(service.showIt)" 
      ng-class="{'name-show':service.showIt, 'name-show-disabled':!service.showIt}">
        {{ service.name }}
    </td>
    <td  ng-class="{'show':service.showIt, 'show-disabled':!service.showIt}">
       {{ service.description }}
    </td>
    <td  ng-class="{'show':service.showIt, 'show-disabled':!service.showIt}">
        {{ service.prices }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

---

Now question remains how to hide all the `services`, so that would be very easy. Loop through each `services` collection element & make `showIt` variable as false.

```
angular.forEach($scope.services, function(service){
   service.showIt = false;
})
```

Also you are using custom event on DOM, I'd suggest you to put this code in directive. So that can get reusable too.

Comment: Thank you, it works on resize, but now when I click on any one they all show.  I need to set them individually on click, and then hide them all on resize.

Comment: @Squirrl Glad to help you. Thanks :-)